# Admob is not showing ads anymore

Tags: c#, google-play, admob

Before this is marked as duplicate, I have already checked other posts, and none of them helped.

My ads were showing just fine at first but they are not showing anymore.

What are the possible reasons? Two friends that have the app told me they see no ads anymore. Is it possible that they watched many ads and now there are no more? Or is it possible that something is wrong? I checked my admob account and everything seems fine, but this is my first app so I am not sure if I am doing things write.

Answer (score 1):

Check your admob policy centre for possible policy violations!

Comment: Just checked. No violations

Comment: Then it should be due to lack of fill rate. There might simply be no ads to display as of the moment in your region where you are testing. You can try mediation for increasing fill rate!